# Access google analytics js properties in own js

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

When I use the Google Analytics Debugger Chrome extension, a bunch of handy properties are returned in the console on page load, such as Session Count or Referring URL. Is there any way I can access these properties in my own Javascript that I write? I'm not sure if the ga.js file makes those publicly accessible or if I'd have to do something fancy.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ga.js stores this information in cookies (which you can access via javascript). Specifically the __utma cookie holds user id and session counter, __utmz has the campaign info (including referrer).

Other info is colllected on every page (browser plugins, screen resolution etc.) or on the google server (timestamp), but of course you do not need Google to get those.

Btw. the new analytics.js uses a single cookie with only one value ( a user id), so the above does not work for universal analytics (which does most of the work on the google servers, not on the client).